# Typedef or rename packs in variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

How do I change name of a pack in variadic template (w/o macroses):

```
template <class _T, class... _Rest>
class MyTuple : public MyTuple<_Rest...>
{
// Yes. It's my tuple.
public:
    typedef _T T; // Ok!

    typedef _Rest Rest; // Problem!
    using URest = _Rest; // ???

    inline Tuple() {}
    inline Tuple(const T&, const Rest&...) {} // Problem!
}

template <class _T>
class MyTuple<_T>
{
public:
}
```

There premonition that this is impossible. And it is better to use template arguments directly in the body of the template.

Comment: It's impossible. You can only use a parameter pack in an expansion. Also, you shouldn't use names starting with an underscore and a capital letter; they are reserved, as are all names starting with two underscores.

Comment: For that matter, `typedef _T T;` is pretty silly in C++11. `auto` and `decltype` generally obselete these `typedef` copies of template parameters.

Comment: rici, What do you mean? They are reserved? Why?

Comment: @Casey: it's very common to `typedef` a parameter to a public name in order to re-export the type. (Eg., `typedef _Key key_type`, from `std::unordered_map`)

Comment: @user1931823: They are reserved for the standard library. The standard library may need to create macros, and that would interfere with the use of those names by user programs, so all names starting with underscore and a capital letter or two underscores are "reserved for the implementation." (Section 17.6.4.3.2, [global.names])

Comment: @rici I didn't say it wasn't common practice - I said it's no longer a necessary practice in C++11. The `key_type` of your `std::unordered_map`, for example, can be recovered from `decltype(std::declval<foo>().begin()->first)`.

Comment: @Casey: but the standard requires it to be available as the `key_type` member of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `typedef` variadic-template. However, I can't see the problem

```
inline Tuple(const T&, const _Rest&...) {}
```

And anyway, you can `typedef` `_Rest` with tuple for example.

```
typedef std::tuple<_Rest...> RestArgs;
```

and from it you can take all types, when you want.